# How to substitute objects in tree-like Scala case class instance with derived objects?

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection, traits, case-class

Suppose I have a set of case classes that represent constants, variables, and unary and binary operations on them, similar to one from "Case Classes and Pattern Matching" chapter in Programming in Scala:

```
abstract class Value {
    def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]): Double
    def evaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = basicEvaluate(varArray)
}

case class Constant(d: Double) extends Value {
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = d
}

case class Variable(i: Int) extends Value {    
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = varArray(i)
}

case class Add(v1: Value, v2: Value) extends Value {
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = v1.evaluate(varArray) + v2.evaluate(varArray)
}

...
```

Then, suppose I have some means to produce expression trees that reuse certain subexpressions many times, and I wish to be able to evaluate the expression efficiently, so that each distinct subexpression gets evaluated only once. For this reason, I introduce a trait

```
trait UsingCache extends Value {
    var cached: Option[Double] = None
    override def evaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = {
        if (cached == None) {
            cached = Some(basicEvaluate(varArray))
        }
        cached.get
    }
}
```

Then, I can do the following:

```
val expr = new Variable(0) with UsingCache
val expr2 = new Add(expr, expr) with UsingCache
expr2.evaluate(Array(5.0))
```

and it works.

My question is - how to implement a function `def extend(value: Value): UsingCache` which would recursively replace each `Value` in the tree with a corresponding `.. with UsingCache` object? I wish to keep this logic decoupled from the individual subclasses of `Value` (e.g., when I add a new operation, it shouldn't contain any code specific for caching). Is there some way to do this using implicit conversion? Or some ideas how to use Scala reflection (I'm using Scala 2.12)?

Comment: I found a bug in your implementation of UsingCache. Your cached value is the same regardless of the value of varArray. See my solution for the corrected version.

Comment: Also, as I wrote in the comments of my answer, my updated answer is memoized and uses tail call optimization.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, case classes are immutable, so your implementation of UsingCache is fine. My mistake. I changed my implementation back to be the same as yours.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I am right after all. Think about it. For your cached Value of type Variable, your evaluate function needs to return a different value if a different array is passed in. So your implementation will return the wrong result in that case. I have changed my answer back to my corrected answer. It's possible to rewrite my code to be more efficient, so that the map in Constant with UsingCache does not have to store a map. But for that, you will have to have a unique class for CachedX, which means more boilerplate, which you said you don't want.

Comment: @AllenHan, you're correct, in my version, the evaluation only works once :) I knew about it, but didn't mention because my code should only serve as an example, and it is irrelevant to the problem I have. In my real intended application, the trait `UsingCache` doesn't store the cached value, but instead it gets an index (at the moment of its creation) in some "global" cache array, which gets reset before each calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Try macro

```
def extend(value: Value): UsingCache = macro extendImpl

def extendImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(value: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  def transformExprss(exprss: Seq[Seq[Tree]]): Seq[Seq[Tree]] =
    exprss.map(_.map(expr => if (expr.tpe <:< typeOf[Value]) q"extend($expr)" else expr))

  value match {
    case q"$expr.$tname.apply(...$exprss)" =>
      val exprss1 = transformExprss(exprss)
      q"new $expr.${tname.toTypeName}(...$exprss1) with UsingCache"
    case q"${tname: TermName}.apply(...$exprss)" =>
      val exprss1 = transformExprss(exprss)
      q"new ${tname.toTypeName}(...$exprss1) with UsingCache"
  }
}

extend(Add(Constant(1.0), Variable(2)))

//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion App.extend(App.Add.apply(App.Constant.apply(1.0), App.Variable.apply(2))) at ...
//Warning:scalac: {
//  final class $anon extends App.Add(extend(App.Constant.apply(1.0)), extend(App.Variable.apply(2))) with UsingCache {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  new $anon()
//}
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion App.extend(App.Constant.apply(1.0)) at ...
//Warning:scalac: {
//  final class $anon extends App.Constant(1.0) with UsingCache {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  new $anon()
//}
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion App.extend(App.Variable.apply(2)) at ...
//Warning:scalac: {
//  final class $anon extends App.Variable(2) with UsingCache {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  new $anon()
//}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  - it has opened the whole new world of Scala macros to me :) However, while `extend(Add(Constant(1.0), Variable(2)))` works perfectly, `val expr = Add(Constant(1.0), Variable(2)); extend(expr)` does not, so probably the macro needs some work. I'm thinking now about working recursively, having obtained the field names (like `v1` and `v2` in `Add`) with the help of reflection, and "compiling" the code like `new Add(v1, v2) with UsingCache` by using a macro. However, I'm still far from a complete solution...

Comment: @AndreySh Right, `val expr = Add(Constant(1.0), Variable(2)); extend(expr)` will not work. `Add(Constant(1.0), Variable(2))` is a runtime value of `expr` and macros are expanded at compile time so don't have access to runtime values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a stack to do a depth-first traversal. It is tail call optimized, so will not suffer from stack overflow. The OP also asked that old cached values be reused, so a map is used for memoization.

```
object CachedValueTest2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val expr1 = Add(Add(Constant(1), Add(Variable(1), Constant(1))), Add(Constant(2), Constant(2)))
    println(extend(expr1))

    val expr2 = Add(Add(Constant(1), Add(Add(Variable(2), Constant(1)), Constant(1))), Add(Constant(2), Add(Variable(1), Constant(2))))
    println(extend(expr2))
  }

  def extend(value: Value): UsingCache = {
    def replace(input: Value, stack: List[(Add, Option[UsingCache], Option[UsingCache])], map: Map[Value, UsingCache]): UsingCache = {
      input match {
        case in @ Constant(d) =>
          val (v, newMap) = map.get(in) match {
            case Some(entry) => (entry, map)
            case None =>
              val entry = new Constant(d) with UsingCache
              (entry, map + (in -> entry))
          }
          popStack(v, stack, newMap)
        case in @ Variable(i) =>
          val (v, newMap) = map.get(in) match {
            case Some(entry) => (entry, map)
            case None =>
              val entry = new Variable(i) with UsingCache
              (entry, map + (in -> entry))
          }
          popStack(v, stack, newMap)
        case in @ Add(v1, v2) =>
          map.get(in) match {
            case Some(entry) => entry
            case None => replace(v1, (in, None, None) :: stack, map)
          }

      }
    }

    def popStack(input: UsingCache, stack: List[(Add, Option[UsingCache], Option[UsingCache])], map: Map[Value, UsingCache]): UsingCache = {
      stack match {
        case head :: tail =>
          head match {
            case (add, None, None) =>
              replace(add.v2, (add, Some(input), None) :: tail, map)
            case (add, Some(v1), None) =>
              val v = new Add(v1, input) with UsingCache
              val newMap = map + (add -> v)
              popStack(v, tail, newMap)
          }
        case Nil => input
      }
    }

    replace(value, List(), Map())
  }

  abstract class Value {
    def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]): Double

    def evaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = basicEvaluate(varArray)
  }

  case class Constant(d: Double) extends Value {
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = d
  }

  case class Variable(i: Int) extends Value {
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = varArray(i)
  }

  case class Add(v1: Value, v2: Value) extends Value {
    override def basicEvaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = v1.evaluate(varArray) + v2.evaluate(varArray)
  }

  trait UsingCache extends Value {
    var caches : Map[Array[Double], Double] = Map()

    override def evaluate(varArray: Array[Double]) = {
      caches.get(varArray) match {
        case Some(result) =>
          result
        case None =>
          val result = basicEvaluate(varArray)
          caches = caches + (varArray -> result)
          result
      }

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If you match with all subtypes of `Value` why not just write `def extend(value: Value): UsingCache = value match {
    case Constant(d) => new Constant(d) with UsingCache;
    case Variable(i) => new Variable(i) with UsingCache;
    case Add(v1, v2) => new Add(extend(v1), extend(v2)) with UsingCache
  }`? Why do you need stack?

Comment: Yes, that's true, you don't need the stack. Your solution is better since it is shorter.

Comment: @AllenHan Actually, having a separate class `CachedX` for each operation `X` is exactly what I want to avoid... It will produce too much boilerplate code and doesn't look nice and concise, like many things in Scala are.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, your solution has a problem (besides the need to mention each specific class) that each recursive call (e.g., in `case Add(v1, v2) => new Add(extend(v1), extend(v2))`) will create different objects to replace `v1` and `v2`, even they were the same object initially. This will make the caching ineffective.

Comment: @AndreySh I understand. I implemented it this way so that I could easily inspect the type by printing it out with println. I am still thinking about how to implement it so that it will be tail-call optimized. I probably won't finish implementing it in time for you to use it, but it is fun to work on. Thank you for sharing your problem.

Comment: @AndreySh If you want to reuse objects, you probably need to keep a map of some kind to stored old instances of UsingCache. Maybe one of Map[Value, UsingCache].

Comment: @AndreySh I used Dymtro's and your feedback to update my answer. It now reuses cached values with a Map and is tail call optimized.